# What is the significance of symmetric part of tensor product of co-vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-forms

For doing vector calculus one uses differential forms which are built out of taking the anti symmetric part of tensor product of co-vectors. These anti symmetric products have very geometric interpretation such as giving out oriented lengths, areas and volumes when fed in the proper number of vectors.

My question is, is there any use for the symmetric part of the tensor product?

Comment: Start with a (pseudo-) Riemannian metric.

Comment: Can a pseudo remanian metric be factored as tensor product of two covectors..?

Comment: Another one is you can view the Riemannian 4 curvature tensor is a symmetric 2 tensor between 2 form.

Comment: No, it’s a sum of ‘em. Most differential forms are likewise not “simple,” i.e., the product of $1$-forms.

Comment: @Burian the Riemannian metric is already a symmetric two tensor. Sth like $$g=g_{ij] du^i\otimes du^j$$

Comment: Right, but I am specifically asking the significance of the symmeteric part of the tensor product not non factorable symmetric tensors

Comment: @JamesChiu This remark requires a lot of explanation, especially since the English is not quite right.

Comment: @Buraian You need to learn some algebra. The symmetric and skew-symmetric tensors form vector spaces.

Comment: Right, I have learned that and I do understand that it means the metric can be written as a combination of basis two forms.. but my question is a bit different: I want to know if there is any application of the symmeteric part which comes out of the tensor products

Comment: Even a “basic” symmetric tensor is a sum of two (or more) tensors, so what you’re saying makes no sense.

Comment: To make sure we're not talking past each other, in the $n = 2$ case, are you talking about the symmetric tensors inside of $V \otimes V$, or are you talking about an operation which maps a pair $(v, w)$ of vectors to $v \otimes w + w \otimes v$?

Comment: The second @joppy